# hebrew text do not inserted correctly in opencart database

Tags: oscommerce, opencart2.x

I have a oscommerce database with hebrew language and text are inserted in "øôàì" type with charset latin1_swedish_ci   . I want to import database to opencart but data are insert in opencart as "רפאל" with charset utf8_general_ci  . My question is how i convert "øôàì" type of data in as "רפאל" before inserted into opencart . Please help me solve it .

Thanks

Comment: I don't get where is the problem... If the characters are already inserted in hebrew, why would you need to convert them to hebrew before that? Anyway, take a look at PHP's `mbstring` extension for that.

Comment: when i import data from oscommerce it is inserted in opencart in this form "øôàì" but i need to as "רפאל"(its actual hebrew text) My question is how i convert "øôàì" type of data in as "רפאל" before insert into opencart .